# Spark kryo_serializers and Broadcast<Map<Object, Iterable<GowallaDataLocation>>> java.io.IOException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, apache-spark, kryo

When I try to access a Broadcast variable I receive this Exception:

> 17/03/26 03:04:23 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 10, 192.168.56.5, executor 1): java.io.IOException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1276)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:206)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:66)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:66)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:96)
>       at GowallaTask$2.call(GowallaTask.java:214)
>       at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:351)
>       at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:351)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
>       at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:917)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:917)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>       at java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:209)
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:162)
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:39)
>       at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoDeserializationStream.readObject(KryoSerializer.scala:244)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$10.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:286)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1303)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.unBlockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:287)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:221)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1269)
>       ... 19 more

I received the exception when I use KryoSerializer

```
    conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
    conf.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.mb", "24");
```

This is my code.

```
JavaPairRDD<Object, Iterable<GowallaDataLocation>> line_RDD_2 = sc
            .textFile("/home/piero/gowalla_location.txt", 2).map(new GowallaMapperDataLocation())
            .groupBy(new Function<GowallaDataLocation, Object>() {

                /**
                 * 
                 */
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -6773509902594100325L;

                @Override
                public Object call(GowallaDataLocation v1) throws Exception {
                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

                    return dateFormat.format(v1.getDATE());
                }
            }).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER());



Broadcast<Map<Object, Iterable<GowallaDataLocation>>> broadcastVar_2 = sc.broadcast(line_RDD_2.collectAsMap());
    //System.out.println(broadcastVar_2.getValue().size());

    JavaRDD<Object> keys = line_RDD_2.keys().persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER());
    line_RDD_2.unpersist();

    keys.foreach(new VoidFunction<Object>() {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8148877518271969523L;

        @Override
        public void call(Object t) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //System.out.println("KEY:" + t + " ");
            Iterable<GowallaDataLocation> dr = broadcastVar_2.getValue().get(t);

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect this happens because you are broadcasting the `line_RDD_2.collectAsMap()` directly: this means the type broadcasted is Map and kryo doesn't know the correct implementation and will use an `AbstractMap` for it's inner work

Like if i do this:

```
Map<String, String> a = new HashMap<String, String>();
a.put("a", "b");
Set<String> c = a.keySet();
c.add("e");
```

i will get unsupported operation for `AbstractCollection`, easily resolved:

```
Map<String, String> a = new HashMap<String, String>();
a.put("a", "b");
Set<String> c = new TreeSet<String>();
c.addAll(a.keySet());
c.add("e");
```

if my guess is right you can probably resolve it like this:

```
Map<Object, Iterable<GowallaDataLocation>> a = new HashMap<>();
a.putAll(line_RDD_2.collectAsMap());
Broadcast<Map<Object, Iterable<GowallaDataLocation>>> broadcastVar_2 = sc.broadcast(a);
```

let me know if this works